# How to fix contents of a subsection to be inside not outside of it

Tags: floats, positioning

I do not know whether what I posted as a title was the best question for my problem or not. I have subsequent subsections  in which I only put sub floats (no text yet). The problem is that the sub floats accumulate all in one subsection! How can I force the PDF to be produced in the same order I did in the `.tex` file? Why the compiled PDF mixes the sub floats of different subsequent sections.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You seem to have been asked for MWEs several times before. Please understand that we are not equipped with any special insight into your computer or code. We only know what you tell us.

Comment: there is no minimum working example for this problem!

Comment: Exactly. There not being an MWE is precisely what you should remedy ;).

Comment: I mean, if I make an example, it will not illustrate the problem. The example will not show any problem.I will try to think of a better way to explain the matter

Comment: Why not? You create the example to illustrate the problem. That's the point of the example. You start with a document with the problem and you delete everything you can without getting rid of the problem. That makes an MWE. But this is a duplicate if there is nothing more going on, so it is best just to refer you the the mother-of-all-answers about float placement.

Comment: ok, I will see the link. If I have a different matter, I will edit the question with some helpful MWE

Comment: Note that the only reason to wrap `\includegraphics` in a `figure` environment is to allow latex to move (float) the figure. You can use the `placeins` package to restrict how far a float floats